# are gaussian quadrature weights constants?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration

Are the weights of gaussian quadrature constants for any given function? Or is it good calculate the weights for each function?

Comment: For a given interval, the weights for pure Gaussian quadrature do not depend on the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weights for Gaussian quadrature depend on the number of points and the dimensions of the interval.  So yes, the weights are constant, regardless of the choice of function.